# Error when enabling data encryption using local key MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, security, ssl, encryption, bigdata

I have successfully encrypted the communication in mongoDB but when I try to enable the data encryption I'm getting errors. I am using the enterprise edition of mongoDB with version 3.2.4. I get the following message in the console:

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
```

But when I look at the logs I see detailed error as follows:

```
Unable to retrieve key .system, error: there are existing data files, but no valid keystore could be located.
Fatal Assertion 28561
```

following is the snippet of my config file:

```
# enable authentication
security:
  authorization: enabled
  enableEncryption: true
  encryptionKeyFile: /home/test/mongodb-keyfile
```

It works fine without the `enableEncryption`, and `encryptionKeyFile` parameters. Could anyone explain what i'm missing here? thanks!

Comment: I have no idea about MongoDB encryption, but I would think that you can't enable encryption of an existing database. Perhaps you can create an empty database with enabled encryption and then copy all data to the encrypted database.

Comment: @Gurkha Well it would help if you understood it. If you want data encryption then you are going to have to start with a blank data directory. So backup the data first, delete the current data directory and set new options. Then you can restore data and continue. The same process applies as to [switching storage engines](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-standalone-wiredtiger/). It's just not possible to switch those options and have the database just do it for you.

Comment: Take a look - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management ... Also, you need to make sure your database is running on WiredTiger storage engine.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm trying to encrypt a brand new instance of MongoDB so the data directory is empty.

Comment: @StanleyKirdey the version of mongoDB I'm using uses WiredTiger storage engine by default. I also tried to manually specify it but without luck. And the link you provided, that exactly what I did and it says valid keystore not found. :(

Comment: @NeilLunn you were correct, my data directory was not empty. It was my mistake to think it will create a new data directory when i change the port that it runs on. Anyways thanks for your answer, saved my day.

Comment: Already answered by Wan but I will add that I am visiting this with the MongoDB support team our account manager. We have instances under automation, but making the change in Ops Manager it will only do part of the upgrade for you. Each member will go into a Start state and then you need to intervene to help the deployment on it's way.

Comment: How do I verify if my encryption is working?

Comment: @jxStackOverflow the startup logs will tell you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoDB's encrypted storage engine supports two key management options:

- [Key Manager](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#key-manager) : Integration with third party key management appliance via the Key Management Interoperability Protocol (KMIP).
- [Local Key](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management): Use of local key management via a keyfile.

Worth mentioning that using a key manager meets regulatory key management guidelines and is *recommended* over the local key management.

If you are using Key Manager option, please see [KMIP Master Key Rotation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-encryption-key/#kmip-master-key-rotation).

Since you are using the Local Key option, if you have a [Replica Set deployment](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/) you could [rotate the replica set member](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-encryption-key/#rotate-a-member-of-replica-set). This would [re-sync](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) data from the un-encrypted to the encrypted `mongod`.

Alternatively if you only have a standalone `mongod`, you could:

1. [Back Up](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) your database files.
2. [Stop `mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes) process.
3. Delete or move existing database files in `dbpath`. Exercise extra caution! -  If you are deleting, make sure you have a [backup data](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/).
4. Restart `mongod` with [--enableEncryption](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--enableEncryption) and [--encryptionKeyFile](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--encryptionKeyFile).
5. Restore backup files to the restarted and encrypted `mongod`.

As an *example*, you could use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to dump the data, and use [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to restore the dump files.

Lastly, note that [MongoDB Enterprise](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise-advanced) edition is a commercially supported product. I'd suggest opening a support case if you have a Commercial Support subscription.

Comment: thank you for your step by step guide. I emptied the data directory, regenerated the local key and started the MongoDB instance. Now its working like a charm.

Comment: I am getting this error: Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--enableEncryption'

Comment: @null1941 The answer above is for MongoDB Enterprise (v3.2+) feature which supports `--enableEncryption`.

Comment: @wan Bachtiar, can you tell me how to use the --enableEncryption option in a yaml file? :)

Comment: @HomerTw https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options

Comment: You should see the value of the field encrypted in the database.

Comment: If I delete dbpath then mongod does not even start