# Initializing mongodb using encryption key

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I've been wanting to benchmark encryption at MongoDB but I'm having an issue when starting mongod.

I've followed the [instructions on configuring encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/#local-key-management), created a keyfile and started mongod using that keyfile, but then I get the following error:

> Unable to retrieve key .system, error: There are existing data files, but no valid keystore could be located

The start command is:

```
mongod --enableEncryption --encryptionKeyFile mongodb-keyfile
```

The log shows:

```
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2719 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=machine  

(...)  

I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine  
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem  
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3422M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),encryption=(name=AES256-CBC,keyid=".system"),extensions=[local={entry=mongo_addWiredTigerEncryptors,early_load=true},,],  
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Unable to retrieve key .system, error: There are existing data files, but no valid keystore could be located**  
I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28561 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 264  
I -        [initandlisten]  

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Any clue what the solution might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when enabling data encryption using local key MONGODB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455265/error-when-enabling-data-encryption-using-local-key-mongodb)

Comment: Hi Nelson Évora, and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a very similar question been answered before; can you take a look at the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36541201/174843 and see if it helps you?

Comment: sorry for not replying earlier... i dont even remeber how i solved it but i think it was something to do with authorization, changed it to 600 and it worked just fine